# Oracle AQ: History Table for Queue Table

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to create a history table for a queue table, that will store all the events of the queues, for a defined period of time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems likely to me that you could use the retention property of the queue to do this. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96587/qsample.htm#158007 and also dbms_aqadm.alter_queue for details. If you really need a separate table then how about creating a multiple subscriber queue and creating an audit subscription that populates the history table. I'd use built in functionality first.

Comment: i can't use the retention time for more than 900 sec due to performance issues in our database that's i thought of a separate table. i will investigate about the audit subscription, maybe that's what i need

Comment: @Khalif: What about a flashback archive? That doesn't depend on the rentention time. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28321/ap_other.htm#sthref1548